# DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory. failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found

Tags: xcode, pdf

In one of my views, I simply want to show a pdf file in a UIWebView.

My code of the header file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FCOMViewController : UIViewController

{IBOutlet UIWebView *fcomWebView;}

//flag to denote if this is first time the app is run

@property (nonatomic) BOOL firstRun;

@end
```

And here the method in the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //Show the procedures PDF

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b777normalprocedures" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[fcomWebView loadRequest:request];
[fcomWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

The app starts fine, does not crash or anything. The referencing outlets are set, but it doesn't show the PDF. Console says:

> DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old
>   directory. failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

The pdf is in the project directory, I have double checked that it is written correctly.

What can I do here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are targeting iOS 8.0:

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b777normalprocedures" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
[_webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: That did it. But there are some ugly black borders. I'll keep watching this issue, and kept the old code commented out, to see what happens with it, when the gold master or beta 7 comes to us developers.

Comment: Yes, this is just a workaround, hoping that Apple fixes this or give us something better.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was with downloaded pdf files which had extensions that I presume was otherwise recognised by UIWebView (aspx,php etc.). When I renamed the downloaded pdf files so that they had a ".pdf" extension the error did not occur.